# google map array items as selectors to load content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

in google map i have an array like this one:

```
 var beaches = [
 ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
 ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
 ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
 ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
 ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 4]
```

];

what i'd like to do is to target beaches[i][0]'s with a jQuery function like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $(/*something here*/).click(function() {
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
            return false;
            });
});
```

(in order to get names and load pages to a div for every different marker)

i know this is dumb question but how can i target beaches individually with this .load function?

---

UPDATED VERSION OF MY CODE (STILL GETTING AN ERROR):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>some places by CATEGORY</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <a href="#"  class="links" onclick="displayMarkers(1);">CATEGORY 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="links" onclick="displayMarkers(2);">CATEGORY 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="links" onclick="displayMarkers(4);">CATEGORY 3</a>

    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div> 
    <div id="content" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; border:1px solid red;"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var home = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88, 151.28);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: home,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });

   var beaches = [
     ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
     ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
     ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
     ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
     ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 4]
   ], markers = [];

   var i, newMarker;

   for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
       newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
       map: map,
       title: beaches[i][0]
     });

     newMarker.category = beaches[i][3];
     newMarker.setVisible(false);

     aL(newMarker);
     markers.push(newMarker);


function aL(m) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', (function(newMarker, i) {
        return function() {
        $('#content').load('content/' + m.getTitle() + '.php');
}
      })(newMarker, i));
}
   }    
   function displayMarkers(category) {
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       if (markers[i].category === category) {
         markers[i].setVisible(true);
       }
       else {
         markers[i].setVisible(false);
       }
     }
   }

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Basically the "something here" has to be or refer to an element or node w/in your page structure. In your case I guess "something" should be marker(s), and in order to do that this might help you: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Comment: Yeah I totally understand that. I just don't know how to call them! By name? Wrap them in HTML elements and give them class? (I tried that and it didn't work) any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map();// map initialization code omitted for brevity...

    var beaches = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 4]
    ], beachMarkers = [];// a placeholder so you'll be able to manipulate the markers later if needed

    for (var i in beaches) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
            title: beaches[i][0]
        });
        aL(marker);
        beachMarkers.push(marker);
    }

    function aL(m) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(m, "click", function() {
            // do whatever you gotta do
            $('#content').load('content/' + m.getTitle() + '.php');
        });
    }
});
```

I had a project which might have similar functionality, in case you're curious; [**it**](http://xn--fct27tsuo05i.tw/)'s in Traditional Chinese, though!

---

**UPDATE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <title>some places by CATEGORY</title> 
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <a href="#" class="links" onclick="displayMarkers(1);">CATEGORY 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="links" onclick="displayMarkers(2);">CATEGORY 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="links" onclick="displayMarkers(4);">CATEGORY 3</a>

        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div> 
        <div id="content" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; border:1px solid red;"></div> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var home = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88, 151.28);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: home,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var beaches = [
                ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
                ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
                ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
                ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
                ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 4]
            ], markers = [];

            var i, newMarker;

            for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
                newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][3], beaches[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    title: beaches[i][0]
                });

                newMarker.category = beaches[i][3];
                newMarker.setVisible(false);

                aL(newMarker);
                markers.push(newMarker);
            }

            function aL(m) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
                    $('#content').load('content.php?id=' + m.category);
                });
            }

            function displayMarkers(category) {
                var i;

                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i].category === category) {
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

A few recommendations:

1. In HTML5, there's not need to self-close (i.e, `META`) tag.
2. Try using **for-each** instead of for-loop; if you insist, declare the index variable w/in the parentheses of the for-loop; unless you need to keep it for further use.
3. I ain't sure whether adding a field to the `google.maps.Marker()` class directly is a good idea; well, at least it works for your project.
4. The `aL()` function you copied was in the for-loop block, which makes its living scope w/in the block, but also makes it defined as many times as the size of the array. So I moved it back out.
5. The third parameter of `google.maps.event.addListener()` is a callback function, you didn't have to wrap it like you did (and `return` to whom!?), plus you didn't utilize either parameter in your anonymous function.
6. I changed the `url` in the `aL()` function, please adjust to fit your needs.

Comment: Your project looks very similar to what i'm trying to achieve and it's pretty awesome even though i can't read Chinese. I think i'm on the right track but i still get an error and i'm not sure what it is that i do wrong. (I'm super grateful for your help btw). please look at updated version of my code above!

Comment: Although there are a few lines that are not best practice, since I ain't sure how well you know about JavaScript as well as the Google Maps API v3, I took the liberty to modified your updated code just a little bit just to *make it work*.

Comment: ahhh thanks for your help but this isn't working. your recommendations are much appreciated! wont be making these mistakes again. my goal with this map was to use links above the map to display makers from the array by type ([i][4]) and once they're on the map enable .load function for every marker to load a page into my little div below the map. i wanted to use [i][1]'s as names of external pages (stored in "content" folder) for the load function. right now i'm not getting any markers on the map at all. category buttons are not working whatsoever.